# Retaining form values in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

I am working on an ROR application and i would like retain form values after the form reloads on some error from the server side so that the user doesn't have to go through filling the form again.

Comment: Rails has this functionality by default..

Comment: After form submission. render the form request with value (@instance Variable) to new action form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard functionality, which is enabled with use of an [`@instance variable`](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2006/11/18/class-and-instance-variables-in-ruby/). This allows you to send data to a Ruby class (controller) and process the returned data in a single instance

You'd do it like this:

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
def new
    @post = Post.new #-> notice instance variable
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

This enables you to maintain the instance of your newly created ActiveRecord object. It means each time you can't submit your form, you'll receive errors with the previously inputted data